# UIApplicationWillTerminateNotitication limitations?

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplicationdelegate, termination

What are the possibilities I have when I receive a `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification`? I want to perform a data task to send some data to my remote server, but if I try to call the method that executes this process the execution stops right there, and it doesn't get called. I can do basic stuff like logging text or data using `NSLog` but I can't do anything more complicated than that? Is it possible, and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: You should save data when your app enters the background, not when it is about to be killed.

Comment: @rmaddy Well, first of all, I dont want to save data, I need to start a very app-specific background process when my app is not active in the foreground (so either in the background or completely killed). This process needs to be initiated BOTH when my app enters the background AND when my app gets killed? How would you deal with the scenario in which the user immediately kills your app without going into background first? Then all data would be lost, wouldn't it?

Comment: "in which the user immediately kills your app without going into background first" If the user kills your app, your app was deactivated at the very least.

Comment: @matt Why? That doesn't make any sense. If I launch my app, and immediately double-tap my home button to swipe up my app to kill it, it gets terminated, but it has NEVER entered the background state. This means the code I have provided for entering the background, never got executed.

Answer (score 0):

The main limitation of `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` is that you will probably *never* receive it. It is basically not worth registering for it.

Comment: It gets called every time I kill my app. You're probably confusing the notification with the delegate method `applicationWillTerminate`, which indeed barely ever gets called (basically never). The notification, however, is ALWAYS received.

Comment: Interesting. In that case, you should downvote my answer! I'm just wrong (if what you're saying is true). I'll have to explore further.

Comment: I believe it will get called if the app is killed when it is in the foreground but inactive (ie double click and immediately swipe up on your app) but not if it is suspended (ie you are running some other app in the foreground , double click and scroll across to your app and swipe up)